# Laravel firebase otp from controller

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, controller, one-time-password

I have beening working on a laravel project using Firebase OTP sms. Anyone guide me how to send OTP from laravel controller, please? I don't wanna send and verify the PIN on blade file using javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Firebase Mobile Number (OTP) authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49608423/laravel-firebase-mobile-number-otp-authentication)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use this library to handle your OTPs. [ichtrojan/laravel-otp](https://github.com/ichtrojan/laravel-otp)